# Memory consuming while passing objects as arguments in PHP

Tags: php, oop

My question is what does consume more memory:

1. Pass an object as an argument in a method
2. Pass ID integer as an argument and then create an object from that id

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Is the end result the same object? Where does the `ID` come from?

Comment: Unless your objects are dealing with many MBs of data, I would call this [premature optimisation](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)...

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

Comment: Object is instance of one row element in database. We have our internal ORM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since objects are always passed by reference in PHP and creating it from an ID may create a duplicate the object if it exists outside of the function, I'd say method 1 is more memory efficient.

Answer (score 1):

2 will consume more real memory because in addition to the object itself, you have to hit the database (unless you are using a smart ORM like Doctrine 2, which keeps a reference to the objects already fetched, to save db hits)

1 will consume no memory at all other than the already used by the object, because you only send a reference to it (in PHP, objects are passed by reference by default)

I would pick 1 any day